# How do I include a skipped answer in a random binary vector?

Tags: r, vector

I am creating vectors of length and total sum value based on yes or no answers from a survey that I administered to a class. This is the code for the vectors:

```
length <- 37
sum <- 29 
Q3_S1 <- c(rep(0, length - sum), rep(1, sum))
```

None of the questions were skipped except for one student skipped question 3. How would I include that skip in my code? Should I just change the length of the vector since it is all values​ of 1 or O?

I am new to R so still learning a lot, any advice is helpful and thanks for the help with the above code from before!

Comment: *"How would I include that skip in my code?"* Not sure I understand. What would be your expected output vector?

Comment: It's better to use variable names which are more context-specific: `length` and `sum` are very useful base R functions, and if you create variables with their names it can cause inconveniences/bugs since those functions are now masked by your variables.

Comment: Students in a class used a survey I created online to answer questions, I am trying to transfer the data into something I can use on R (I created my own CSV code on excel that I can use) however I wanted to see if I could generate my own vectors with the correct length and sum myself. However, because one student skipped one of the questions I am not sure what to do there. I won't be doing anything with the actual data, as I can't really run any kind of sats on it, I just want to be able to show the students how to create your own vectors and what I did in R.

Answer (score 0):

Your total length would not change but you need to add another variable which has a skip count and use a different number to represent that count (say 2).

```
total <- 37
yes_count <- 29 
skip_count <- 1

c(rep(0, total - yes_count - skip_count), rep(1, yes_count), rep(2, skip_count))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can call `rep` once by specifying the `times` which can take a `vector` of lengths equal to the same length as `x`

```
rep(0:2, c(total - yes_count - skip_count, yes_count, skip_count))
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
```

#### data

```
total <- 37
yes_count <- 29 
skip_count <- 1
```